# OSSEC HIDS on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ossec

The question is more about architecture to choose then coding per se. I have my app deployed on AWS ECS (cluster made of ec2 instances running containers). How can I install OSSEC HIDS in that setup? As a side container for every app container or it should be centralized somehow?

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb **"One process per container"**, you should not install any agent in a docker container.

You can follow two approaches

- Install OSSEC HIDS agent on [ECS  optimized AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) which will run on EC2 host that run the container, your ESC cluster will use this AMI for all future container.
- Or Push ECS logs to cloud watch and place OSSEC HIDS with cloud watch and ELK.

For ECS optimized AMI, create custom AMI and configure the agent on that rest of the procedure will be same as standard EC2 machine.

[image]

[how-to-monitor-host-based-intrusion-detection-system-alerts-on-amazon-ec2-instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-monitor-host-based-intrusion-detection-system-alerts-on-amazon-ec2-instances/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Right now I think I need part of this flow: ECS EC2 machines issues reported to CloudWatch (don’t need whole ELK stack). So as far as I understand you I need to build custom EC2-based AMI where installed OSSEC HIDS manager will send some issues to CloudWatch?

Comment: yes the EC2 AMI should be custom but that AMI should be base on ECS optmized AMI which also contain ECS agent and other optimization for docker

Comment: How OSSEC HiDS installed on this custom AMI connects to CloudWatch?